# How to write this pandas function in polars

Tags: python-polars

I want to rewrite this line from Pandas in Polars

ts = aux.set_index(date_col, drop=True).resample("Q").sum()

I tried this:

ts = aux.select(pl.all().sort_by(date_col)).set_sorted(date_col).collect().upsample(time_column=date_col, every="3mo")

being aux a lazyframe.

I get this error:

thread '' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: ComputeError(ErrString("cannot advance '2021-08-31 00:00:00' by 3 month(s). If you were trying to get the last day of each month, you may want to try `.dt.month_end`"))', /Users/runner/work/polars/polars/polars/polars-time/src/upsample.rs:120:83

Comment: Does `every="3mo_saturating"` error? It would help if you provided a full runnable example e.g. even a dataframe with 2 dates.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you set a reproducible example

You don't need `upsample` here, but `groupby_dynamic`. E.g.:

```py
import polars as pl
import numpy as np
from datetime import date

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'date': pl.date_range(date(2020, 10, 30), date(2021, 6, 1), eager=True),
})
df = df.with_columns(values=pl.arange(0, len(df)))

print(df.groupby_dynamic('date', every='3mo').agg(pl.col('values').sum()))
```

outputs

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌────────────┬────────┐
│ date       ┆ values │
│ ---        ┆ ---    │
│ date       ┆ i64    │
╞════════════╪════════╡
│ 2020-10-01 ┆ 1953   │
│ 2021-01-01 ┆ 9675   │
│ 2021-04-01 ┆ 11377  │
└────────────┴────────┘
```